# MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException: 'A write operation resulted in an error. cannot index parallel arrays'

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing, nosql, parallel-arrays

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }

[BsonElement("Prop01")]
public int Prop01{ get; set; }

[BsonElement("Prop02")]
public int Prop02{ get; set; }

[BsonElement("Prop03")]
public string[] Prop03{ get; set; }

[BsonElement("Prop04")]
public List<Test> Prop04{ get; set; }
```

I'm inserting above structure/model in mongoDB using C# (Dot Net Core), but I'm receiving following exception:

**MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException: 'A write operation resulted in an error.
  cannot index parallel arrays [Prop03] [Prop04]'

Inner exception
  MongoBulkWriteException`1: A bulk write operation resulted in one or more errors.
  cannot index parallel arrays [Prop03] [Prop04]**

I don't know the reason why I'm receiving above exception.

I already tried different tricks from last two days but not succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally problem resolved!

I was applying database indexing on Array and List fields in Parallel, which is not allow in MongoDB.